# Get errors while throwing an array() as Exception

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to pass an array as Exception. Which I'll later encode into json.

```
try {
    class myException extends Exception {
        private $params;
        public function setParams(array $params) { $this->params = $params; }
        public function getParams() { return $this->params; }
    }

    throw new myException(
        array(
            'error' => array(
                'status' => true,
                'code' => '12',
                'note' => 'Does NOT contain application/json'
            )
        )
    ); 

} catch (myException $e) {
    print_r($e->getParams());
}
```

But keep getting the following errors:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for myException([string
>   $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]) in
>   /home/domain/script.php:79 Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/domain/script.php(79): Exception->__construct(Array)
>
> #1 {main} thrown in /home/domain/script.php on line 79

---

Is it even possible to pass arrays?

If so, whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Exception::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php) require a string as a first argument. If you want pass an array, you should override the constructor.

```
class myException extends Exception {
    private $params;
    public function setParams(array $params) { $this->params = $params; }
    public function __construct(array $params = array(), $code = 0,  Throwable $previous = NULL) {
        $this->setParams($params);

        parent::__construct('', $code, $previous);
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error when using that: `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method myException::setParams() in /home/domain/script.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /home/domain/script.php(79): myException-&gt;__construct(Array)
#1 {main} thrown in /home/domain/script.php on line 25`

Comment: Line 25 is where `$this->setParams($params);` is.

Comment: why have you removed `public function setParams(array $params) { $this->params = $params; }`? you should keep the rest of the class.